# signal handler with sighup

Tags: c, signals, handler

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <string.h>

void handler (int sig);
int count;

int main() {

    struct sigaction act;
    memset (&act, 0, sizeof (act));


    act.sa_handler = handler;
    if (sigaction (SIGHUP, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror ("sigaction");
        exit (-1);
    }

    int count = 0;
    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
        count++;
    }

}

void handler (int signal_number){
        printf ("count is %d\n", count);
}
```

I assume i am doing this right, how would I go about call sighup within the command line? It needs to call sighup to print out my count.

Comment: why is the output always "count is 0"? Why isnt the count++ processing

Comment: You re-declared count in main. The sig handler is reading the global "count".

Comment: fixed it. knew it was overlooking somhting on the count

Comment: @DDukesterman [avoid using printf in a signal handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kill -SIGHUP <pid>`, where `<pid>` is the process ID of your code.

Answer (score 4):

Technically it is not safe to do I/O in the signal handler, better to set a flag, watch for it, and print based on the flag.
On a posix system, you should be able to "kill -HUP " from the command line to send the signal.

Comment: Not only printf, all function do  signal interrupts, malloc(), here is  [List of authorized functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this in console:

```
ps -a
```

read out the pid of your program

```
kill -s HUP target_pid
```

[Here you have](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?kill%201) a manual page for kill with a list of signals.

EDIT: even simpler you can use killall:

```
killall -HUP nameofyourbinary
```